# Dragging and Dropping Folder from outlook to windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, outlook

Does anyone know how to drag and drop a whole folder from outlook onto a windows form?  I am able to drag and drop MailItems quiet easily, however, it seems with I am unable to do so with a folder. The ultimate goal I am attempting to accomplish is to drag a folder from my inbox to a windows form and be able to iterate through the sub folders and mail items within the folder that was dropped onto the windows form.

For mail items I do the following within the DragDrop event handler:

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
{
     Outlook.Application outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
     foreach (object mailBoxItem in outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection)
    { // Handle mail items }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Explorer class provides the [CurrentFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866719(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a Folder object that represents the current folder displayed in the explorer. But I don't think you can drag and drop the folder somewhere.